# how do i differentiate array values in octave?

Tags: arrays, matlab, command, octave

i'm implementing assignment that i have ECG signal as one dimensional array file input, do some processing in order to detect heart rate.

first step is too differentiate values using 5 point difference equation to get rid of low frequency values, I've searched about differentiation in octave but all I found is about polynomials. so how do I implement this in octave/mat-lab commands?

thanks

Comment: ECG is over `5-20Hz` if I'm not mistaking so you need a sharp high-pass filter.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, maybe you want to compute the slope (an approximation of the derivative) of your signal using 5 points, this can be easly achived using for example:

```
load ecg;
n=5
for i=n+1:length(ecg)
    Y(i-n) = (ecg(i) - ecg(i-n))/n;
end

subplot(2,1,1); plot(ecg)
subplot(2,1,2); plot(Y)
```

Is this the result you expect?
[image]

Comment: i did z = diff(y, 5);plotting z the output was totally unclear signal i wish i can upload the photo

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Pan-Tompkins` method on R-peak detection,

`ecgSig` being your ECG signal with sampling frequency `Fs`,

```
t=(0:size(ecgSig,2)-1)/Fs;
ecgSig = circshift(ecgSig,[0 5]) - ecgSig;

subplot(211)
plot(t,ecgSig);
subplot(212)
plot(t,ecgSig);
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your support but my question is clear i just want to differentiate one dimensional array, then i should smooth the signal using moving average method, this answer is not helping.

Comment: i did z = diff(ecgsig, 5); plotting z, but the output was so noisy i hope i can upload the photo but there's no option to upload in a comment